# I am not able to find callback in first two fragments of viewpager in activity

Tags: android

Scenario: I  have three fragments in ViewPager in activity.

Fragment One

FragmentTwo

FragmentThree

I noticed that switching from fragment one to three onPause() method is  called
but when I switched from fragment one to two onPause is not  called

Problem: I want to show some data in FragmentOne's TextView with a webservice on button  click.I clicked that button and data is shown But I  noticed when I  switch from one to two and then come back to fragment one data is shown. I want to hide that data when I  come back to one.   Is  there any  callback . ?

Comment: I would implement a ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html

Comment: Put `onStart() ` method in fragment one and clear your textview in 'onStart() ' so that when fragment is visible the textview is cleared.

Comment: But  it is  not calling  onStart()  in  fragment one  when we go  from one to  two  and  back  from  two to  one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand Viewpager first. viewpager creates fragment in advance before and keeps so that there is smooth flow when you switch, like if you are on Fragment 2. viewpager creates 1 and 3 and keeps.

and when you are on Fragment 3 it retains Fragment 1.
Anyways you can increase the limit of viewpager with this

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int num)
```

you can understand all the lifecylce of fragment in Viewpager by putting Logs in onPause and onResume in viewpager fragments.

Anyways coming back to your prob. you need to have custom interface like [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwju4e_RsuvNAhVBQo8KHUkkDq8QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Flooksok.wordpress.com%2F2013%2F11%2F02%2Fviewpager-with-detailed-fragment-lifecycle-onresumefragment-including-source-code%2F&usg=AFQjCNFcLlfqi_zld8l8ZDpgrPcLFRV2VA&sig2=COnlUiym7H2P5_Bnv-x9ug&bvm=bv.126130881,d.c2I&cad=rja) . answer helped me too

Comment: yea but it is not the solution. default value of `setOffscreenPageLimit` is always 1. setting it to 0 will not work. i suggest you to implement custom interface solution

Comment: Yes  this method is working for setOffscreenPageLimit (3)  not setOffscreenPageLimit (0)  whenw  we want   to show  text  when we return to one

Answer (score 0):

Its happening because Fragment One is in backstack. Dont keep FragmentOne in backstack while switching to FragmentTwo and on Back press of FrgamentTwo call switchContent for FragmentOne again .

Comment: Can you tell code for not  keeping  fragment in backstack in  viewpager?

Comment: sorry , just whole view pager concept slipped out of my mind  and posted answer. sorry again